# Why is this not an obsolete comment?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flagging

I recently flagged Pearson's comment on [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/can-change-in-suns-polarity-affect-satellites) as obsolete in response to Tildal's call for obsolete comment flags:

> Edit your question and put it in. It's pretty common to edit questions after the fact to add such details. – PearsonArtPhoto ♦ Aug 7 at 17:08

This comment was in response to Hash responding to Pearson asking for a source. Hash responded with a link to the source, and Pearson asked him (?) to edit it in.

I checked, and the post was edited and the source added. Why is this not an obsolete comment?

Comment: Who said that it isn't? You've flagged it, and I agreed that it is obsolete - so: deleted. I'm sure @PearsonArtPhoto would agree himself, but it's sometimes impossible to keep track of all the comments we leave. That's why the option to flag is there - to bring stuff to the attention of moderators. And also the need to keep the comments section short and to the point. But flagging is fine, there's no "punishment" for frequently asking attention of moderators LOL ;)

Comment: @Tildal I flagged it once before and it got declined.

Comment: Maybe the mod missed it? It's sometimes easier to attach a descriptive reason for the flag, but it's also pretty easy for us to miss the darn button that's supposed to handle it as suggested LOL

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm posting an answer to not have this question linger in the unanswered questions list, so just for the sake of housekeeping:

The issue brought forward by the OP was successfully resolved. The comment in question was deleted as obsolete, after being flagged once more. The reason for the original flag declination was attributed to either a system error, or a wireless mouse running dangerously low on battery juice. Whichever the cause, it couldn't have been any of the moderators' fault, because moderators are of course infallible and do not click on other than intended buttons. This has been proven many times over and is in itself indisputable.

[image]

Thanks for your understanding!

Sincerely,

[Space Moderators](https://space.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)